# Two-tailed or one-tailed test?

Tags: statistics

The study using 139 students studies the maximum amount of alcohol consumed. Based on data are there differences between males and females in the maximum amount of alcohol consumed? (Use alpha= .05

Men                            Women

mean=8.2                      mean=5.6

s=5.9                       s=5.7

n=54                        n=85

I'm not sure if i should be using one-tailed or two-tailed test. 
I'm also not sure if my t.05 value is correct. I know you need to double the critical value column if it's two-tailed test. Am I starting this problem correct way? thank you![image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure if i should be using one-tailed or two-tailed test.

Yes, a two-tailed test is correct because the maximum amount consumed by men can be more or less than that of women. Experimentally, you should establish the rejection region *before* you collect the data, and as it is possible in theory at least that men could drink less than women, you should include that.

In general, the two-sided test is typically viewed as a better way to perform a hypothesis test, because the one-sided test makes it easier to reject the null hypothesis after you get the data by choosing the single big rejection region to be on the side the data suggests.

> I'm also not sure if my t.05 value is correct.

For $\alpha=0.05$, yes, $1.96$ is the $97.5$th percentile of the null distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Since alternative hypothesis is $\ne$, So it can be < or >. That's why it will be two tailed test.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not sure whether there are differences in the amount of alcohol consumed by males and females, you may assume that the consumption is the same in both cases. This means that your null hypothesis says that there is no difference in the means of both the populations.
**H0: μ1 = μ2**

Since the hypothesis is direction-less (not leaning towards one population being greater), the test is two-tailed.
With the two-tailed test, because you’re not sure which side of the distribution
the difference could land on, you have to divide the error and put a little on each side. So you need a larger critical t-value to obtain a significant chance of rejecting the null hypothesis.
(However, if you make an assumption that men consume more alcohol than women, then the hypothesis is directed and thus one-tailed)